# What do the blue dots on the map indicate?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I know the green dots are "useful" items or "upgrades" to your equipment, and that gray is "not useful". What are the blue ones there for though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blue dots indicate Mythical items. Similarly, pink/fuschia items are Transcendent.